# How to save pixels after normalization

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, computer-vision, normalization

I want to normalize my images and use them in the training. But I couldn't find a way to save images after making changes below...How can I save it?

```
files = ["/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/images/evre1/xyz.png",
         "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/images/evre1/xty.png"]

def normalize(files):
  for i in files:

      image = Image.open(i)
      new_image =image.resize((224,224))
      pixels = asarray(image)
      # convert from integers to floats
      pixels = pixels.astype('float32')
      # calculate global mean and standard deviation
      mean, std = pixels.mean(), pixels.std()
      # print('Mean: %.3f, Standard Deviation: %.3f' % (mean, std))
      # global standardization of pixels
      pixels = (pixels - mean) / std
      # confirm it had the desired effect
      print(pixels)
      # mean, std = pixels.mean(), pixels.std()
      # print('Mean: %.3f, Standard Deviation: %.3f' % (mean, std))
  

normalize(files)
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the images are still of type `PIL.Image.Image` you can use the [`save`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) method to save the images.

Comment: I don't know why but pixels values don't change.( I saved it and checked the pixels. )

Comment: What code are you using to save the images? It seems you are converting the images to a numpy array using `asarray`, so therefore I would simply save the data as numpy arrays instead of images, which can be done using [`numpy.save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html).

Comment: Okay, I saved it with numpy.save. But how can I employ it to training set? Could you please give advice on that?

Comment: t = np.load(outfile)

img_w, img_h = 224, 224

img = Image.fromarray(t, 'RGB')

img.save('test.png')

img.show()

It doesnt show nothing ..